# How to use mobile default Picker in React web app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker

I need to use respectively the default iOS and Android Picker in a React web app.
 I've found a Picker component in React Native which apparently does what I need:
 https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html 
Is there any way to import the component in React? Alternatively is it possible to toggle the default picker within React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project on Github to do exactly what you want called react-native-web which can be found at: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

I looked through the repository and found it has the  component you want to use.

Comment: I am on a project using ReactJS and I imagine it would be out of scope for this project to switch to RN Web. Is there a similar iOS picker element for ReactJS itself?